# How do you automatically update the build name of an Azure pipeline if a boolean parameter is set to true

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

Below is an excerpt from a large yml pipeline. I'm trying to manually update the build name if a parameter is set to true using the build.updatebuildnumber command. However I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

```
steps:- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Set the name of the build (i.e. the Build.BuildNumber)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: | 
 [string] $buildName = "CIPEnabled" + " " + "$Build.BuildId"
Write-Host "Setting the name of the build to '$buildName'."
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$buildName"
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be $(Build.BuildId) instead of $Build.BuildId.
Like that:

```
steps:- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Set the name of the build (i.e. the Build.BuildNumber)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: | 
 [string] $buildName = "CIPEnabled" + " " + "$(Build.BuildId)"
Write-Host "Setting the name of the build to '$buildName'."
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$buildName"
```

Comment: You shouldn't interpolate variables into an inline script, this opens up your pipelines to script injection vulnerabilities. You should use environment variables instead, i.e. `$env:BUILD_BUILDID`.

Comment: Build.BuildId is a predefined variable that is set by the system and it's read-only. How can it be used for injection?

Comment: In this specific case, it's not a problem. However, it's a bad practice and should be avoided.